# Dynamic binding variables to existing dom elements

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular5

I have a component that presents dynamically loaded SVG. Svg is being loaded to variable `svgSelector`. Component template is simple:

```
<div #selectorContainer [innerHTML]="svgSelector | safeHtml"></div>
```

Until now everything is ok - SVG displays correctly. Now I want to bind attributes for some of the elements to variable. Eg. insinde SVG I have:

```
<path fill="#00ff00" d="m1319.0166 570.7281l17.700806 0l0 26.771667l-17.700806 0z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

I would like to bind value of the `fill` attribute to variable. How do I do it?

I get the reference to my selectorContainer and I have it available:

```
@ViewChild('selectorContainer') selectorContainer: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectorContainer.nativeElement.querySelector('svg') // <-- my SVG DOM element

}
```

What next? Is there a way I dynamically bind variable to any of this dynamically created DOM elements?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding with square brackets `[]`? i.e.

```
<path [fill]="varName" ... ></path>
```

Or using `{{}}`? i.e.

```
<path fill={{varName}} ... ></path>
```

Comment: I wrote, that I get the SVG dynamically from the backend.